# Jquery to modify all anchor tag href on a page and extract key request parameters from href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i need to replace all the href's in my page by a onclick event which has few of the parameters from the query string

here is a sample anchor tag

```
<a href="google.com?businessunit=Products&dataSegement=BOTH_PERIOD&endDate=12%2F06%2F2011&d-49489-s=8&d-49489-p=1&d-49489-o=2&catid=3">Demo Anchor</a>
```

another sample

```
<a href="google.com?businessunit=Products&dataSegement=BOTH_PERIOD&pubgrpid=6&endDate=12%2F06%2F2011&d-49489-s=8&d-49489-p=1&d-49489-o=2&marketid=1analysisType=conversion&catid=3">Another sample</a>
```

i need to extract the values of d-49489-s, d-49489-p, d- 49489-o and 
 change anchor tag to something like

```
  <a href="#" onclick="callMethod(d-49489-s,d-49489-p, d-49489-o )">
```

Comment: @micha well that was just a sample i need the values corresponding to these request parameters as method parameters

Comment: I think you want to use onmousedown because if you change onclick it won't replace it fast enough for that what you want.

Comment: can you post a second sample link? it helps for parsing the query string to know if there is a consistent format

Comment: @well might be but the main problem is how do i extract those parameters and add onclick event to it

Comment: @NoviceCoder: have you been able to try any of the posted solutions as yet? Do they work, or are they still problematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
$('a').each(
    function(){
        var h = this.href;
        var r = h.split('&');
        var reqs = [];
        for (i=0;i<r.length;i++){
            if (r[i].indexOf('d-') == 0){
                reqs.push(r[i].substring(0,r[i].indexOf('=')));
            }
        }
        $(this).attr('onclick','callMethod(' + reqs.join(',') + ')');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J9PRL/).

References:

- jQuery, from the [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/):

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- JavaScript, from the [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/):

  - [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 1):

### http://jsfiddle.net/9t2dP/1/

```
$('a').each(function(e){
    var queryString = this.href;
    queryString = queryString.substring(queryString.indexOf('?'), queryString.length);

    var params = new Array();

    while (queryString)
    {
        var start = queryString.indexOf('&d-')+1;
        var end = start+9;
        if (start) { //if param found, save and truncate query string
            params.push(queryString.substring(start, end));
            queryString = queryString.substring(end, queryString.length);
        }
        else
            queryString = '';
    }

    var functionCall = 'callMethod('+params[0]+', '+params[1]+', '+params[2]+');';
    $(this).attr('onclick', functionCall);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do this with the BBQ plugin:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

It'll go through all hrefs on a page and edit them. It let's you tokenize the query parameters really easily.  There are examples on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go through all the links on the page. Use unobtrusive JavaScript to intercept clicks to the links and then return false in the event handler to prevent the browser from navigating to the URL specified in the anchor's href attribute.

Also, if you are generating the page yourself, you don't have to parse the href, you can use html5 `data-` attributes to store the function arguments for your JavaScript calls:

HTML:

```
<a href="asdf.html?a=b&c=d" data-ajax-params="{&quot;a&quot;: &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;: &quot;d&quot;}">Test</a>
<a href="asdf.html?a=b&c=d" data-ajax-params="[&quot;b&quot;, &quot;d&quot;]">Test</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
    //first link will return object with key=value pairs, second link will return an array with just the values
    console.log($(this).data('ajax-params'));
    //do something with the parameters
    
    
    //make sure to return false to prevent the browser from navigating to href URL
    return false;
  });
});
```

Of course, instead of using the `data-` attribute, you can always do some parsing of the href as suggested in other answers. But I would not replace all the hrefs when the page is loaded. It's simply an overhead to replace all href attributes, while the user might click only on one of them, or maybe leave the page without clicking anything!

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amiuhle/4tEpR/)